# Pocketsphinx simply listening for one command

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, pocketsphinx-android, android-speech-api

I have successfully created a speech to text app which is able to open activities based on recognising keywords.  At the moment for me to start the Speech to text feature I need to click a button.  I now do not want to manually press the button and want to use a continuous listener to trigger the button.

I have been looking into using pocketsphinx and have added a keyphrase "listen to command" once this keyphrase is heard I want the button to be automatically pressed which is then followed by a sequence of commands I can add into the code.  I do not need offline speech to text etc and hence I am using Google's speech to text option but am planning to use pocketsphinx to trigger the google's speech to text feature.

Below is most of the code that I partly modified from pocketsphinx:

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

 /* Named searches allow to quickly reconfigure the decoder */
 private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
 private static final String FORECAST_SEARCH = "forecast";
 private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "digits";
 private static final String PHONE_SEARCH = "phones";
 private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";

 /* Keyword we are looking for to activate menu */
 private static final String KEYPHRASE = "listen to command"; //adjust this keyphrase!

 private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
 private HashMap < String, Integer > captions;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  // Prepare the data for UI
  captions = new HashMap < String, Integer > ();
  captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
  captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
  captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
  captions.put(PHONE_SEARCH, R.string.phone_caption);
  captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
  .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

  // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
  // so we execute it in async task

  new AsyncTask < Void, Void, Exception > () {
   @Override
   protected Exception doInBackground(Void...params) {
    try {
     Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
     File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
     setupRecognizer(assetDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     return e;
    }
    return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
    if (result != null) {
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
     .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
    } else {
     switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
   }
  }.execute();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  recognizer.cancel();
  recognizer.shutdown();
 }

 /**
  * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
  * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
  * for final result in onResult.
  */
 @Override
 public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
  if (hypothesis == null)
   return;

  String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
  if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
   switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
  else if (text.equals(DIGITS_SEARCH))
   switchSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH);
  else if (text.equals(PHONE_SEARCH))
   switchSearch(PHONE_SEARCH);
  else if (text.equals(FORECAST_SEARCH))
   switchSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH);
  else
   ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
 }

 /**
  * This callback is called when we stop the recognizer.
  */
 @Override
 public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
  if (hypothesis != null) {
   String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
   makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

 /**
  * We stop recognizer here to get a final result
  */
 @Override
 public void onEndOfSpeech() {
  if (!recognizer.getSearchName().equals(KWS_SEARCH))
   switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
 }

 private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
  recognizer.stop();

  // If we are not spotting, start listening with timeout (10000 ms or 10 seconds).
  if (searchName.equals(KWS_SEARCH))
   recognizer.startListening(searchName);
  else
   recognizer.startListening(searchName, 10000);

  String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
 }

 private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
  // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
  // of different kind and switch between them

  recognizer = defaultSetup()
   .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
   .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))

  // To disable logging of raw audio comment out this call (takes a lot of space on the device)
  .setRawLogDir(assetsDir)

  // Threshold to tune for keyphrase to balance between false alarms and misses
  .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45 f)

  // Use context-independent phonetic search, context-dependent is too slow for mobile
  .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)

  .getRecognizer();
  recognizer.addListener(this);

  /** In your application you might not need to add all those searches.
   * They are added here for demonstration. You can leave just one.
   */

  // Create keyword-activation search.
  recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);

  // Create grammar-based search for selection between demos
  File menuGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "menu.gram");
  recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);

  // Create grammar-based search for digit recognition
  File digitsGrammar = new File(assetsDir, "digits.gram");
  recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);

  // Create language model search
  File languageModel = new File(assetsDir, "weather.dmp");
  recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);

  // Phonetic search
  File phoneticModel = new File(assetsDir, "en-phone.dmp");
  recognizer.addAllphoneSearch(PHONE_SEARCH, phoneticModel);
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(Exception error) {
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
 }

 @Override
 public void onTimeout() {
  switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
 }
```

I am not interested in most of the commands, I just simply want the app to listen as soon as it is opened (which it currently does) and as soon as a person says `Listen to command` it then presses a button which I have set an id of `bVoice`

If someone can kindly help me modify the above code so that I know what to delete and what to add that will be greatly appreciated.  Also note that if there is a much easier method of doing this please feel free to share (having a custom key phrase isn't also necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, and you do not need to "push the button", you can directly call button callback instead and perform actual steps you are interested in.

```
public class PocketSphinxActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

 private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
 private static final String KEYPHRASE = "listen to command"; //adjust this keyphrase!

 private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
  super.onCreate(state);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
  .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

  new AsyncTask < Void, Void, Exception > () {
   @Override
   protected Exception doInBackground(Void...params) {
    try {
     Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
     File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
     setupRecognizer(assetDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
     return e;
    }
    return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
    if (result != null) {
     ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
     .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
    } else {
     recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
    }
   }
  }.execute();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  recognizer.cancel();
  recognizer.shutdown();
 }

 /**
  * In partial result we get quick updates about current hypothesis. In
  * keyword spotting mode we can react here, in other modes we need to wait
  * for final result in onResult.
  */
 @Override
 public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
  if (hypothesis == null)
   return;

  String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
  if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE)) {
        recognizer.cancel();
        performAction();     // <- You have to implement this
        recognizer.startListening(KWS_SEARCH);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {}

 @Override
 public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {}

 @Override
 public void onEndOfSpeech() {}

 @Override
 public void onTimeout() {}

 private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) throws IOException {
  // The recognizer can be configured to perform multiple searches
  // of different kind and switch between them

  recognizer = defaultSetup()
   .setAcousticModel(new File(assetsDir, "en-us-ptm"))
   .setDictionary(new File(assetsDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
   .getRecognizer();
  recognizer.addListener(this);

  // Create keyword-activation search.
  recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(Exception error) {
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(error.getMessage());
 }

 public void peformAction() {
    // do here whatever you want
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, when you wrote "performAction()" do I need to replace this with something such as "performClick" for example?  such as:   Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    c.performClick();
                }
            }, 500);    //Automatically click the 'Blogin' button after 500ms

Comment: `performAction` is just a generic name, you can replace it with `performClick` if you like that name more.

Comment: And you do not need a handler, you can just run it directly

Comment: So all I need to do for example is assign a button in the xml file and then just use the snippet of code in place of your "performAction" line?

Comment: Any chance you can complete that code with for example a button called 'c' which is automatically clicked after 500ms.  I'll accept your answer once it is updated and working

Comment: I have implemented the code but it does not seem to work, the screen constantly shows "preparing the recognizer" and does not go into the keyphrase string

Comment: Is there a way to implement both 'RecognitionListener' and also 'View.OnClickListener' in the same public class?

Comment: @NMC your app must recognize "listen to command"?how do you define it? please answer me. this is my biggest question!!!

Comment: You simply type in your key phrase in the code as well as in the string.xml file